# Is it possible to stop fsck_hfs running on external drive?

Tags: osx-mavericks

I have a 2 TB external firewire drive that won't unmount to be erased.
I think it won't unmount because fsck_hfs is running, but I don't know how to confirm what drive fsck is running on.
**If** I can confirm that it's running on the external drive, can I kill the process?
All I really want to do is erase the drive so I can start fresh with a new backup (assuming the drive is still good) but I can't because it won't unmount...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't care about the contents of the drive, you can be forceful here.

Use `fuser -ck <mountpoint>` to kill any process holding the mount open, and the you can do whatever you want to erase and format the drive.